# Laravel 4. Как правильно составить запрос mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Всем привет! Не могу понять как составить правильно запрос.
Хочу сделать сортировку по несколько видам тегам.
Например в запросе есть три тега: фантастика,боевик,комедия = $catid
хочу через запрос получить такой вид:

```
|  1 |      фильм 5     |фантастика,боевик,комедия|
|  2 |      фильм 4     |        фантастика,боевик|
|  3 |      фильм 8     |       фантастика,комедия|
|  4 |      фильм 9     |           боевик,комедия|
```

Но при таком запросе

```
$query = Film::groupBy('film.id')->with('categories');
$query = $query->join('category_film', 'film.id', '=', 'category_film.film_id')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->whereIn('category_film.category_id', $catid);
```

Он ищет где есть упоминание этих тегов.
Получаю такой вид:

`|  1 |   фильм 1 |   фантастика|
 |  2 |   фильм 2 |      комедия|
 |  3 |   фильм 8 |       боевик|
 |  4 |   фильм 7 |   фантастика|
 |  5 |   фильм 10|       боевик|
 |  6 |   фильм 9 |      комедия|`

Сами таблицы:

films содержит:

`| id |      name |otherNames|   slug|
 |  1 |   фильм  1|   films 1|films_1|
 |  2 |   фильм  2|   films 2|films_2|
 |  3 |   Фильм  3|   films 3|films_3|
...`

category содержит:

`|  id|       name|         slug|
 |  1 |фантастика |   фантастика|
 |  2 |   комедия |      комедия|
 |  3 |   боевик  |       боевик|
...`

category_films таблица связки.

`|   films_id|  category_id| 
 |          5|            1|
 |          5|            2|
 |          5|            3|
...`

буду рад решения данной задачи.

Comment: Для начала покажите как выглядят ваши таблицы фильмов, жанров и их таблица связки.

Comment: Дополнил первое сообщение, буду рад если составите sql запрос для mysql запроса.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае скорее всего в модели прописана не та связь, поскольку - проверив, ваш код у меня выбрал все варианты, а не только один из.

В модели Film связь должна выглядеть так:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_films');
}
```

Вариант чистого SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM category_films cf
  JOIN films f ON f.id = cf.films_id
  JOIN category c ON cf.category_id = c.id
  WHERE p.id = <id>;
```

Lara style:

```
DB::table('category_films')
    ->groupBy('films.id')
    ->Join('films', 'films.id', '=', 'category_films.films_id')
    ->Join('category', 'category.id', '=', 'category_films.category_id')
    ->get();
    -------------Можно добавить, если нужно
    ->Where()
    ->select()
    ->orderBy()
```

Comment: А как осуществляется сортировка от большего совпадении к меньшему?

Comment: @Виктор А для этого  вопроса стоит создать новую тему, чтоб другие в дальнейшем тоже могли найти ответ=) А если вы получили ответ на ваш вопрос по этой теме, отметьте его отвеченным)

Comment: Вроде в этом и был суть вопроса и даже пример показал как должно получиться, искать сразу по нескольким категориям, от большего совпадений к меньшему...